# How can a String.prototype be declared in Aurelia?

Tags: string, prototype, aurelia

I am porting some plain JS code into Aurelia and I want to include String.prototype.xxxxx types, but I have not been successful.

So, This:

```
    String.prototype.uncamelize = function() {
    ...
    }
```

results in:
ERROR: Parsing error:Unexpected Token (on first line)

So for Aurelia, how can I prototype functions for String?

Comment: The error you got is not related to Aurelia. I think there is something else going on that caused issues in your app. Can you have a check at previous lines to see if any SyntaxError occurs?

Comment: Where are you adding this code? This has nothing to do with Aurelia. You are adding this in some place where you shouldn't. Please provide the full context.

Comment: I tried to add it within main.js, app.js, inside it's own class and inside a common class.
I'm used to plain vanilla JS, so I do puzzle about how Aurelia handles things.

Comment: Found my problem and it was:  me.
I set my prototypes in the constructor of a global class.

Comment: You should answer your own post instead of in the comments so that others know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem and it was: me. 
I set my prototypes in the constructor of a global class.